Как отобразить браузерную версию элементов страницы при печати print?
Есть задача, стилизовать печать HTML страницы. Сайт на бутстрапе, там флекс блоки.
При выводе на печать, браузер делает элементы как в мобильной версии (т.е. как на планшете), в связи с чем, получается много листов.
Подскажите как можно сделать так, чтобы при печати выводилась браузерная форма?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Printing

может тут есть дубликаты => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html+%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c
